# D3.js .exit and .enter not working in forceSimulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The definition of my `forceSimulation` is like this:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(function (d) {
        return Math.max(12* (d.target.r), 600);
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(function() { return -100}))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height/ 2))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d){return d.r}).strength(1));
```

In my code, I call the following draw function whenever a change in the `forceSimulation` should occur.

```
function draw(graphNodes,graphLinks) {

    console.log("DRAWING");
    console.log(graphNodes);
    console.log(graphLinks);

    graphLinks = mergeLinks(graphLinks);

    //Update the visualisation
    link = link.selectAll(".line").data(graphLinks);

    //Exit should come first
    link.exit().remove();

    link = link.enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", 5)
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("stroke", function(d){ return getLineColor(d)});

    node = node.selectAll("circle").data(graphNodes);

    //Exit should come frist
    node.exit().remove();

    node = node.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            var rad = getNodeRadius(d, graphLinks);
            d.r = rad;
            return rad})
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return getNodeColor(d); })
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return  d.id});

    //Create the foreignObjects for the text or images
    img = img.selectAll("bookimage").data(graphNodes);

    img.exit().remove();

    img = img.enter().append("foreignObject")
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.r*2})
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.r*2})
        .attr("x", function(d){return (d.x )})
        .attr("y", function(d){return (d.y )});

    //Create the content in the nodes
    img.append("xhtml:div")
        .attr("class", "img")
        .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id + "T"})
        .html(function(d) {return getBookImage(d)});

    txt = txt.selectAll("label").data(graphLinks);

    txt.exit().remove();

    txt = txt.enter().append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#FFF")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-family", "helvetica")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name })
        .each(function(d) {
            d.width = this.getComputedTextLength();
        });

    simulation.nodes(graphNodes).on("tick", ticked);
    simulation.force("link").links(graphLinks);

    //If there are new nodes, or the books are moved restart the visualisation
    if (visRestart) {
        //RESTART THE VISUALISATION
        visRestart = false;
        console.log("RESTART");
        simulation.alpha(1).restart();
     }


}
```

This function gets called with different `graphNodes` and `graphLinks` (I've checked through print statements) but the visualisation is never changed. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `forceSimulation` is the one moving the nodes around you need to update the [nodes](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_nodes) and the [links](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_links) of your simulation.

In this example by Mike Bostock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795 he updates the simulation in the `restart` function like this:

```
simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link").links(links);
simulation.alpha(1).restart();
```